# Can we use View to get consecutive seconds data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to get each second random data from the view.Basically, I am fetching few data from a table and doing a union with the current time to generate random data.Bellow is my query of View:

```
SELECT
A, 
B, 
C, 
Status
FROM dbo.table1_data
WHERE (
            StartTime <= (SELECT        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) AS time)
    )
Union
Select 
    '135A' as A,
    163993 as B,  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) AS C, 
    ROUND(((6 - 0 -1) * RAND() + 0), 1) as Status
```

But it is not adding new data with the current timestamp in every execution.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this expression `(SELECT        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108) AS time)`

Comment: generating time in hh:mm:ss format

Comment: Can you please provide an expected result. It isn't clear to me .

Comment: If you want to get the time portion of `GETDATE()` why not just use `CONVERT(time, GETDATE())`?

Answer (score 0):

Your way of converting time was a bit wrong, try the following:

```
SELECT        A, B, C, Status
FROM            dbo.table1_data
WHERE        CONVERT(TIME(0), StartTime) <= CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE())
Union
Select   '135A' as A
        , 163993 as B
        , CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE()) AS C
        , ROUND(((6 - 0 -1) * RAND() + 0), 1) as Status
```